# Why dir doesn't show all Python object attributes?

Tags: python, object, methods, attributes, scipy

Why do some object methods/attributes not show up when I call `dir` on the object?

Example:

```
from scipy import sparse
e = sparse.eye(2)
'H' in dir(e)
```

returns `False`.  But calling `e.H` works just fine (returning another sparse matrix object).  Why is this so, and how can I see these hidden attributes?

I'm using Python 3.5.1.

Comment: They may have overridden the `__dir__` method. I sometimes use `help(e)` and `e.__dict__`. I'm not sure about my answer though, so I'll leave it as a comment, and let others elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

`e.H`, `e.A`, `e.T` are pseudo-properties of the sparse matrix object.

`shape` is a property. In `sparse.base.py` I find

```
shape = property(fget=get_shape, fset=set_shape)
```

while the `dict` only contains:

```
In [121]: e.__dict__
Out[121]: 
{'_shape': (2, 2),
 'data': array([[ 1.,  1.]]),
 'format': 'dia',
 'maxprint': 50,
 'offsets': array([0])}
```

`get_shape` probably accesses `_shape`.  `set_shape` probably limits our ability to change `_shape`.

I don't know of a neat way of finding all the defined properties for an object like this.  Ideally they should be listed in the documentation, but `sparse` documentation is not ideal.

There is an `e.getH` method, which returns the same thing as `e.H`, so I suspect there's a piece of code, probably in some superclass

```
H = property(fget=getH)
```

Nope - in `sparse.base.py` I find a redefinition of `__getattr__`, so it's an entirely different mechanism (not property and not `__dict__`):

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr == 'A':
        return self.toarray()
    elif attr == 'T':
        return self.transpose()
    elif attr == 'H':
        return self.getH()
    elif attr == 'real':
        return self._real()
    elif attr == 'imag':
        return self._imag()
    elif attr == 'size':
        return self.getnnz()
    else:
        raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
```

In `ipython` I can fetch this with `In [152]: e.__getattr__??` or `sparse.base??`.

`getattr` can be used to fetch all these attributes and properties (and methods)

```
In [161]: getattr(e,'shape')
Out[161]: (2, 2)

In [162]: getattr(e,'_shape')
Out[162]: (2, 2)

In [163]: getattr(e,'H')
Out[163]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [164]: getattr(e,'transpose')
Out[164]: 
<bound method dia_matrix.transpose of <2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>>
```

With the `inspect` module I can get a list of `members`, e.g.

```
[i[0] for i in inspect.getmembers(e)]
```

but that still doesn't list these special ones defined in the `__getattr__` method.