# Why does question mark not always work in iPython?

Tags: ipython

Sometimes when I type question mark, like this:

```
data["mass"]?
```

I get a syntax error. I have to use `help(data["mass"])` in order to get the information. Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that `?` (and `??`) works best when applied to a variable or function name, not an expression.

```
 x = data['mass']
 x?

 y = 1.232
 y?

 z = 'astring'
 z?
```

There may be some expressions that work, but generally no.  I use it most to get information on a function, not an arbitrary object.  In the above expressions `y?` gives me information about `float`, the `type(y)` creator.

---

I suspect `?` uses the completer

http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.completer.html

> The evaluation of the NAME.NAME... form may cause arbitrary application defined code to be executed if an object with a **getattr** hook is found. Since it is the responsibility of the application (or the user) to enable this feature, I consider this an acceptable risk. More complicated expressions (e.g. function calls or indexing operations) are not evaluated.

`scipy.sparse` matrices are an example of class that defines its own `__getattr__`.

From `%magic`

```
%pinfo:
    Provide detailed information about an object.

    '%pinfo object' is just a synonym for object? or ?object.
%pinfo2:
    Provide extra detailed information about an object.

    '%pinfo2 object' is just a synonym for object?? or ??object.
```

`%pinfo` appears to return `not found` in cases where `?` returns `syntax error`.

```
In [265]: %pinfo data['mass']
Object `data['mass']` not found.
In [266]: %pinfo x+1
Object `x+1` not found.
In [267]: %pinfo data.get
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in method get of dict object at 0xb2d700ac>
Docstring:   D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

Comment: For ref [the documentation says](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#dynamic-object-info) *"Note that the dynamic object information functions (?/??, %pdoc, %pfile, %pdef, %psource) work on object attributes, as well as directly on variables. For example, after doing import os, you can use os.path.abspath??."* I guess that index lookups aren't included.

Comment: Attribute look ups imply never having a side effect of creating something new. Indexing, however, can create new objects which may be time consuming (slicing a list), or mutate the object (`defaultdict`). That attribute look ups cannot do these things isn't strictly true, but there is an expectation that this is the case.

Comment: @Dunes: Attribute lookups can be expensive or have side effects just like indexing. For example, the `I` attribute of `numpy.matrix` instances requires a potentially quite expensive matrix inverse calculation.

Comment: `x.shape?` for a numpy array gives me a rather uninteresting blurb about tuples.  `x.view?` is more interesting since it gives the docs for a method.  I use the `x.<tab>` nearly as often.

Comment: `numpy` and `scipy` play games with attributes.  I just showed that a number of the `scipy.sparse` attributes are produced by a custom `.__getattr__` method, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36212242/901925